# GeoDjango Point fields widget does not show coords properly

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango

in a Django application I use PointField

```
point = models.PointField(_('Point'), null=False, blank=False)
```

I use normal long lat system, so `[50, 15]` should be a point in Europe, in the Czech Republic I think. But then in the administration there is a nice interactive widget with a map which shows the point somewhere in the Red sea. When I check the value in the code of the widget It says the coords are completely different (some numbers in millions), but when I want to output the coords to the console, it says normaly `[50, 15]`

```
print(Datapoint.objects.get(pk=pk).point)
# Output: SRID: 4326; Point(50, 15)
```

Does anyone have an idea what could go wrong here?

I know there are more SRIDs, but even when I change every possible SRID attribute (Model, AdminSite, Form, Widget), still does not work...

Thanks, RA

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using `django.contrib.gis.admin.OSMGeoAdmin` as the base class for your admin class. The problem has to do with different standards for reading and displaying the order of longitude and latitude. GeoJSON assumes the first element in the coordinates tuple is longitude and the second latitude. Older systems assume the opposite, latitude and then longitude. Now in the internet age it seems that longitude-latitude has won.

So it's most likely a display issue, not a data issue. OSMGeoAdmin for some reason goes with the older order. LeafletGeoAdmin with the newer.

Try installing django-leaflet and then use the base class `leaflet.admin.LeafletGeoAdmin`. In my opinion it is more pleasant and has more options anyway.

Steps as I recall:

1. `pip install django-leaflet`
2. add to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py: `'leaflet',`

Source: django-leaflet: https://pypi.org/project/django-leaflet/

Update how it goes.